# What bank deposits are insured in the U.S.?

Tags: united-states, banking, deposit-insurance

What kind of bank deposits in the U.S. are insured against banks going under?  What do I need to look out for to make sure my money is safe?

Answer (score 5):

The FDIC insures deposits up to $250,000 per depositor, per bank, **for each ownership category**.  The [ownership categories](http://www.fdic.gov/deposit/deposits/insured/ownership.html) are:

- Single Accounts
- Certain Retirement Accounts
- Joint Accounts
- Revocable Trust Accounts
- Irrevocable Trust Accounts
- Accounts Employee Benefit Plan Accounts
- Corporation/Partnership/Unincorporated Association Accounts
- Government Accounts

You and a spouse could collectively have $750,000 of insured deposits at a single bank if you each had a single account, and a joint account together.

Comment: This answer could be better if it elaborated on how to verify that your bank is FDIC insured.

Answer (score 2):

Currently the FDIC insures deposits up to $250,000 per person per bank. The following products are covered if your bank is FDIC insured.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Federal_Deposit_Insurance_Corporation#FDIC-insured_products

Answer (score 2):

Bank and most Credit Union deposit accounts (including CDs) are guaranteed by the Federal government by the FDIC and NCUA, respectively.

Some state-chartered credit unions use private insurance, you'll want to be careful about storing lots of money in those institutions.